# iOS overlay and animation is not opening my simulator's camera photos

Tags: ios, swift, animation, overlay

I am new to iOS development but I am trying to follow a [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6236502-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) tutorial on adding animations and overlays to videos but I am getting some unexpected behavior. For some reason when I press the pickButton it takes me to my "Memories" instead of my camera roll (see the image below) in my simulator. What is really strange is that when I run the code the debugger is completely blank. There is nothing that seems to be running according to the debugger, but the app itself appears to be working when I look at it in the simulator. There are several print statements that should display in the debugger but I do not see anything. You can download the entire codebase (its pretty small) from the hyperlink above. I am not sure why this is not working.

```
@IBAction func pickVideoButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    pickVideo(from: .savedPhotosAlbum)
  }

  private func pickVideo(from sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.sourceType = sourceType
    pickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    pickerController.videoQuality = .typeIFrame1280x720
    if sourceType == .camera {
      pickerController.cameraDevice = .front
    }
    pickerController.delegate = self
    present(pickerController, animated: true)
  }
```

[image: screen snapshot]

Comment: simulator doesn't work for this

Comment: You are correct Fattie! I tested it on my device and it worked just fine. I didn't realize these were limitations of a simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you call this function `private func pickVideo(from sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType)` and what `UIImagePickerController.SourceType` are you handing over? Best would be to show us the code that calls the function.

> On the other hand, **working with the camera and importing images** is always kind of difficult on the simulator, since it cannot access the camera and therefore has no images. Try to run the code and an actual device *(Your iPhone)*. Maybe it is working on there.

Try this out, and if not working, provide the code that calls the `pickVideo` function.

Comment: christophriepe you are correct. It turns out that this was a simulator issue. I was able to test it on my device and it works just fine. I wish I got some kind of error message that told me it would not work or some kind of indication it was not going to work.

Comment: @Part_Time_Nerd Glad to be able to help you. Happy coding!